# jQuery autocomplete integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I found this jQuery and I want to integrate it into my project. My question is how do I apply that "source"?

Because on my inputs I receive all from the database and I cannot write nothing before in html or jQuery!

Actually I use a wicket component to do auto-complete but that component is buggy because if I resize the browser, the list is not aligned below the input, and because of that I am trying to find a better way.

If anyone can hep me :)

```
var $element = $('.my-autocomplete');
var $testinput = $element.find('.my-autocomplete-input');

$testinput.autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
  });
```

**Fiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CSypd/36/

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work, what's the issue there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Client Side**

```
    $("#element _id").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDepartmentStuff")',  
                        //generates into a url. eg http://www.site.com/MyPage/GetEmployeeDepartmentStuff?filter=....
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            filter: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(eval(data), function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.em_name,
                                    dp_Name: item.dp_Name
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    })
                },
                maxLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {                   
                    $("#Deparment").attr('value', ui.item.dp_Name);
                }
            });
```

**Server-side**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [CompressFilter]
    public ActionResult GetEmployeeDepartmentStuff(string filter = "")
    {
        SomeRepository repo = new SomeRepository();
        return repo.GetEmployeeDepartmentStuff(filter);   //returns a JSON result
    }
```

Don't know what langue you use for your server-side code, but you need to have a web method/service/something exposed that accepts the parameter "filter" (see above), or whatever else you want to send back.... also don't forget to include the jquery libraries in your markup

Answer (score 0):

The simplest idea would be to get your source array via ajax call.